# Too many collisions cause lag

Tags: rigid-bodies, godot, kinematics

I have a scene with one kinematicbody (planet) and I am adding rigidBodies and shooting them at the planet. The problem is, that when I have more than 500 in my scene, the game becomes really laggy and I do not know what to do to prevent it.

**What I've tried:**

Removing the collision detection on bullet - this solved the problem, but I want to keep the collisions, for further use

Swapping RigidBody for Kinematicbody and shooting it - this did not solve the problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Profile your program and use the data to find the bottleneck. You may be surprised what you find

Comment: Sure will do, but I think the collisions are the source of this problem. Anyway, how do I profile the program ?

Comment: Have a look at Godot's debugging tools and their functionality here: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/debug/overview_of_debugging_tools.html

Comment: Maybe they collide with each other? Try setting up a collision layer for the rigidBodies and a collision mask to ignore them colliding with each other. https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html#collision-layers-and-masks